# Submit two forms with one button and post to two different APIs

Tags: javascript, html, api

I hope what I'm asking makes sense, but basically let's say I have these forms:

```html
<form method="post" action="/a/url/goes/here">
<!-- some fields --> 
</form>

<form method="post" action="/a/different/url/goes/here">
<!-- some checkboxes --> 
</form>


<button>SUBMIT</button>
```

Basically, when the button is pressed the first form's information gets sent to one API and the 2nd forms information gets sent to another API#

Thanks all!

Comment: And the problem/question is?

Comment: You have to use Ajax for that, you need asynchronous calls, otherwise each form submit reloads the page -> https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Answer (score 1):

Simply make a form with all the fields you needed for both APIs

```
<form action="action_path" method="post">
   All the data you need should be in here. Between these form tag.
</form>
```

And in the `action_path`, you can separate the data as per the requirements of the APIs and call those APIs sending the data.

lets say you have all the data in $_POST. Assign the data to variable like

`$a = $_POST['name'] , $b = $_POST['name2']` and so on.

The you can do anything you want with those data. Send `$a to API1` and `$b to API2`

Comment: Hi, thanks for this but how do I split the data in the path? Is there a way you can give an example?

Comment: lets say you have all the data in `$_POST`.  Assign the data to variable like `$a = $_POST['name'] , $b = $_POST['name2']` and so on. The you can do anything you want with those data. Send `$a` to API1 and `$b` to API2.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply submit one form and then separate the data.
for example you have this form:

```html
<form method="post" action="your_action">
  <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

you can send the data  to a specified page that has the role of submitting the data to multiple APIs. something like this if you are dealing with php:

```
$data1 = $_POST['input1'];
$data2 = $_POST['input2'];
```

and then send $data1 to API1 and $data2 to API2 :)